# Animation in css3

Tags: html, css, animation, transform, transition

I just created an css3 animation and I have a problem.
When I hover over my text, above appear a line and everything may have to be great, but I don't know how to move this line at the bottom of text.
I've trying with transform:translateX but it does not help.

There is my code:

```
.line
{
font-family:Tahoma;
width:0px;
height:1px;
background:black;
transition:width 0.4s ease ;
-moz-transition: 0.4s ease ; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: 0.4s ease ; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: 0.4s ease; /* Opera */

}

div:hover

{

width:85px;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DashDesign/SD58Z/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/DashDesign/SD58Z/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the inner div one pixel to the top, give it an opaque background and remove the height restriction from the parent div.

```
.line div{
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
    bottom:1px;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SD58Z/8/)